# Как сделать пинг-понг анимацию? (1 раз в одну сторону, 1 раз в обратную)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Нужно что бы анимация пошла сначала в одну сторону, а потопом в обратную сторону. После одного единственного нажатия на кнопку. НЕ БЕСКОНЕЧНАЯ АНИМАЦИЯ.

Сейчас она двигается только в одну сторону. Как исправить?

```
@State private var anim: Bool = true

TextField("description", text: $descr)
            .blur(radius: anim ? 0 : 10)
            .animation(.easeInOut)

Button("Commit"){
    if (self.descr == "")
    {
          withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 4)) {
               self.anim.toggle()
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать отдельную повторяющуюся анимацию и использовать ее.

Пример по Вашему коду:

```
// Создаем требуемую нам анимацию, которая будет повторяться бесконечно
var repeatingAnimation: Animation {
    Animation
        .easeInOut(duration: 4)
        .repeatForever()
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Description", text: $descr)
            // Что и как будем анимировать, от начального значения 0 при anim = false и 10 при anim = true
            .blur(radius: anim ? 10 : 0)
            // Анимируем? Тогда используем ранее созданную анимацию, а для остановки передаем nil
            .animation(anim ? repeatingAnimation : nil)
        Button("Commit") {
            if self.descr.isEmpty {
                self.anim.toggle() // Запускаем/останавливаем анимацию
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Суть в том, чтобы использовать бесконечно повторяющуюся анимацию когда надо, а когда не надо - убирать ее

---

К сожалению, у анимации в SwiftUI нет completion block или чего подобного, чтобы можно было прописать .onAnimationCompleted { // Some work... }.

Поэтому сделаем пару лишних телодвижений и завернем TextField так, чтобы он выполнял то что нам надо:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var descr: String = ""
    @State var onError = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            BlurredTextField(title: "Description", text: $descr, onError: $onError)
            Button("Commit") {
                if self.descr.isEmpty {
                    self.onError.send()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BlurredTextField: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var onError: PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>
    @State private var anim: Bool = false
    // Да, банально используем таймер для реверса анимации
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    @State private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = Set()
    private let animationDiration: Double = 1

    var body: some View {
        TextField(title, text: $text)
            .blur(radius: anim ? 10 : 0)
            // Так как анимация простая, вернем обратно для уменьшения строчек
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: animationDiration))
            .onAppear {
                self.onError
                    .sink(receiveValue: self.toggleError)
                    .store(in: &self.cancellables)
        }
    }

    func toggleError() {
        // Инвалидируем таймер, дабы избежать блымканий
        timer?.invalidate()
        // Гоняем туда-сюда. Можно заменить на значение радиуса блюра
        anim = true
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: animationDiration, repeats: false) { _ in
            self.anim = false
        }
    }
}
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно обьяснение как именно работает данный код? Что бы я понял логику и как повторить, если понадобится

Comment: @Andrew магия там, как всегда у Apple. Танцуют по тем же проприетарным граблям, что и с UIKit. Ну и пока все же лучше не трогать это тормозное глючное поделие под названием SwiftUI. Обновил ответ, постарался разъяснить.

Comment: Только мне нужна не бесконечная анимация.... Мне нужно 1 проигрывание анимации в 2 стороны. Например: контрол размывается(блюр), а потом снова становится четким. И больше анимация не повторяется. Просто 1 раз проигрывается анимация сначала в одну сторону, потом в другую, а потом останавливается. А не бесконечная цикличная.

Comment: @Andrew недопонял из вопроса, что нужно один раз сделать реверс. Обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: `onAnimationCompleted` можно самому реализовать через `animatableData`, тогда станет понятно почему нету такого метода в SwiftUI

Comment: Все же добавлю простой ответ. SwiftUI не всегда может распознать как делать анимацию иногда надо писать свой `animatableData` по этой причине реализовать универсальный метод `onAnimationCompleted ` пока под вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

на английском SO подсказали более элегантное решение

```
extension View {
    func addOpacityBlinker<T: Publisher>(subscribedTo publisher: T, duration: Double = 1)
        -> some View where T.Output == Void, T.Failure == Never {
            self.modifier(OpacityBlinker(subscribedTo: publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher(),
                                         duration: duration))
    }
}

struct OpacityBlinker: ViewModifier {
    @State private var isBlurred = false
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>
    var duration: Double

    init(subscribedTo publisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>, duration: Double = 1) {
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.duration = duration
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .blur(radius: isBlurred ? 10 : 0)
            .onReceive(publisher) { _ in
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: self.duration / 2)) {
                    self.isBlurred = true
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.duration / 2) {
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: self.duration / 2)) {
                            self.isBlurred = false
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

и пример использования:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    //ивент по которому будет срабатывать пинг-понг анимация
    let blinkPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Button("Blink") {
                // генерим ивент по нажатию на кнопку
                self.blinkPublisher.send()
            }
            Text("Hi")
                //подпись на блюр-анимацию по ивенту
                .addOpacityBlinker(subscribedTo: blinkPublisher)
            Text("Hi")
                //подпись на блюр-анимацию по ивенту, но анимация другой длительности
                .addOpacityBlinker(subscribedTo: blinkPublisher, duration: 0.5)
        }
    }
}
```